# Responsive icon solution when changing icon sizes in OS X Finder

Tags: finder, preferences

I rarely use the Finder outside of list view, but sometimes I need to view a large folder of images to select from. By default, the icons/image previews are not large enough for my needs, so I increase the size of the thumbnail icons in the bottom right of the finder window to determine which image to use. Easy peasy.

When I do this, however, the icons don't cascade down. Instead, I get a scrollbar with icons out of view to the right. This is so Windows 2000.

My solution is to go to `View > Clean Up By > Name` and all icons are shown with only up and down scrolling and are the size I want.

Is there some way I can have it so when I increase icon preview size in the Finder, that all images stay inline?

I don't need to set a default size for all icons to load. I prefer the default size for most use cases, aside from this one.

See below for an example showing my workflow issue.

tl;dr I want responsive design applied to my finder icons!

[image: responsive finder workflow]

Answer (score 3):

You can have the folder contents auto-arranged in icon view via a few settings in `View > Show View Options` (<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>).

When you select the files to be `Arranged By` the criteria you prefer and select `Use as Defaults`, the icons are automatically re-organised on-the-fly. Note that you don't need to select `Always open in icon view`, as in the example image below.

These default settings will be used for all folder that don't have folder-specific settings applied, before or after setting the defaults.

You have to restart Finder, e.g. by `killall Finder` before the new defaults are used.

[image: example of folder settings]
<sup>(Image borrowed from [a SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/561208/10694))</sup>